# How to convert QString with special characters into a byte stream to send it via Linux pipe

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt, pipe

I have a QString containing a special character (µ) encoded in UTF-8:

```
QString data = "197,45 \xc2\xb5m";
```

I need to send that string via a Linux pipe to another program. I tried to convert the string into something like this:

```
char msg[15];    
for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    msg[i] = data.toUtf8()[i];
}
msg[data.length()] = '\0';
```

I send `msg` to the pipe, but I only receive "197,45 µ", not "197,45 µ**m**". I try to read the data on the read end with:

```
char data[15];
read(fd, data, nbytes);
```

I don't know much about character/string conversion, so I would be glad if you could explain how I should approach this problem. Thank you.

Comment: You want the length of the UTF-8 sequence, not the length of the string of `QChar`. Something like `data.toUtf8().length`?

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, that would make more sense. However if I change it to `msg[data.toUtf8().length()] = '\0';` I receive one more byte, but it looks like this `197,45 µ?`

Comment: Is that after changing both places that use `length()`?

Comment: @IanAbbott No, I only changed one line. Forgot the `for` loop. Then it seems to be working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing seems to be mainly "serializing the data" into a binary pipe, so an option that could make sense is to use a `QDataStream` which is designed for that purpose.

Something like:

```
QByteArray buffer;
QDataStream stream(&buffer, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

QString data = "197,45 \xc2\xb5m";
stream << data;

sendToPipe(buffer.constData(), buffer.size());
```

And the similar on the other side, using `operator>>` to read the data from the stream.

```
QByteArray buffer(dataPtr, size);
QDataStream stream(buffer);

QString data;
stream >> data;
```

Comment: That is an interesting approach. But as I mentioned in the comment above, it's working pretty reliable now. Do I get any advantages if I switch to your idea?

Comment: I think the advantages of this approach could be:
- Staying higher-level: Serialization details are mostly solved by Qt, so no need to bother with that (unless you need something really specific). QDataStream offers a few options (e.g. endianness, etc).
- Scalability: If you think you may want to transfer more data than a single string in the future, this is maybe easier to add data. But it depends on your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

It is conceptually wrong to store UTF-8 encoded bytes in a QString. Use QByteArray for that, OR use `QString::fromUtf8()` to convert your UTF-8 string literals to a proper QString. To go back, use the `qUtf8Printable` macro or `QString::toUtf8` to get a `QByteArray`.

Comment: Thanks for your thought, and you might be right.But that QString is part of legacy code I have to deal with now and I don't dare to change anything.